# Should it be possible to delete documentation topics without providing a reason?

Tags: discussion, documentation

See https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/81137 which deleted the entire topic [unspecified behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/4939/unspecified-behavior) and moved the examples to [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/1812/undefined-behavior).

I want to roll back this change but I can't even figure out why it happened.

I've seen [Examples deleted from Documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329596/examples-deleted-from-documentation/329672) but in this case it appears there really is no reason given. The edit just says "Delete topic".

Answer (score 6):

The topic was deleted because *all* of the examples were moved to [a different topic](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/81137?draftId=67887). This is indicated by the automatic comments:

[image: deletes topic, moved 3 examples out]

It is possible to edit those automatic comments to add details on *why* the examples are being moved, but... Doing so isn't exactly obvious: you have to go back and edit one or both of the drafts, then re-submit.

We should probably make that easier.